# Debugging an exception in a background task

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a background task that throws an error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object). I would like the debugger to stop when the exception happen, but it doesn't. I have enabled all "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". I'm pretty sure it has to do with use of async / await.

The below code replicates the behavior. The output of the program is as expected:
Hello!
Error: xxx

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Test().TestMethod();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public async void TestMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                throw new Exception("xxx"); // Debugger should stop the execution here
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Double check your exception settings, you probably don't have Visual Studio set to break when the specific exception type that is being thrown is unhandled:

[image]

Comment: Hm. I thought VS would stop at all exceptions. And, actually, when I insert throw the very same exception in the main program (e.g. before Console.WriteLine) it does so indeed. On the other hand, when I provoke a divide by zero, the debugger really stops in the background task.

Comment: Yea they provide those settings so that you can opt to ignore certain exceptions that may be expected while debugging

Comment: Actually I think it is the <All Common Language Runtime Exceptions not in the list> that should help, but it doesn't.

Comment: So I still have no clue how to have the debugger stop at the exception point.

Comment: What's they type of the actual exception that's being thrown and does it wrap any other exceptions?

Comment: It's "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". What does it mean to wrap another exception? Inside the task. there is no try-catch block, if that's your question.

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is the exception message, NullReferenceException should be the type but I wanted to make sure you weren't getting another type of exception with that message.

Comment: By wrapping another exception, I mean if there is an inner exception. Maybe posting the exception details will help.